# Checking if List of Strings exists in a String

Tags: python-3.x, list

The following code executes sucessfully

```
excluded_strings = ['excluded', 'decrypted', 'extracted_pdf_text.txt']

def excl_file_with_str(rec_file_name):
   
    string_match = [True for excluded_string in excluded_strings if excluded_string in rec_file_name]

    if True in string_match:
        return None
    else:
        return rec_file_name
```

However, the below not. Throwing error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'string_match' referenced before assignment

```
excluded_strings = ['excluded', 'decrypted', 'extracted_pdf_text.txt']

def excl_file_with_str(rec_file_name):

    for excluded_string in excluded_strings:
        if excluded_string in rec_file_name:
            string_match = True

    if True in string_match:
        return None
    else:
        return rec_file_name
```

Comment: The error is being thrown because you are trying to access the value of the string_match variable before it has been assigned a value. To fix the error, you can initialize the string_match variable to False before the loop, and set it to True inside the loop if there is a match:

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to below untested code.

```
excluded_strings = ['excluded', 'decrypted', 'extracted_pdf_text.txt']

def excl_file_with_str(rec_file_name):
    string_match = False

    for excluded_string in excluded_strings:
        if excluded_string in rec_file_name:
            string_match = True
            break

    if string_match:
        return None
    else:
        return rec_file_name
```